# find minimum spanning tree using depth first search in C

Tags: c, algorithm, graph, depth-first-search, minimum-spanning-tree

I'm trying to implement an algorithm in c which finds MST using DFS. I've already found the DFS algortihm and i understand it pretty well. I also know that i should follow these steps to achieve my purpose :

1 Run DFS till you find an edge going backwards or DFS stopped. If stopped return G.

2 On the circle that is constructed by the backwards going edge find the heaviest edge and remove it from G.

3 Return to 1.

Here is the DFS code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
void DFS(int);
int G[10][10],visited[10],n;    //n is no of vertices and graph is sorted in array G[10][10]
void main()
{
    int i,j;

printf("Enter number of vertices:");
scanf("%d",&n);

    //read the adjecency matrix
    printf("\nEnter adjecency matrix of the graph:");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
            fscanf("%d",&G[i][j]);

    //visited is initialized to zero
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        visited[i]=0;

    DFS(0);
}
void DFS(int i)
{
    int j;
printf("\n%d",i);
visited[i]=1; // éviter cycle
for(j=0;j<n;j++)
    if(!visited[j]&&G[i][j]==1)
        DFS(j);
}
```

I need your help to implement the full algorithm or at least some advices. That would be much appreciated. Thank's in advance.

Comment: you can do this easily if you use BFS... Did you try MST with BFS?

Comment: No didn't tried it yet. Do you have any path i can follow to learn about it ?

Comment: Are the edge weighted between nodes?

Comment: @AliAkber If the edges do not have weights, any tree is a MST. If they do, BFS does not work. I do not see how BFS can be useful for finding the MST.

Comment: @user2040251 that's why i asked it... because the OP said `find the heaviest edge and remove it from G.` so the edge must be weighted and he has to use `kruskal` or `prims` algo to get the MST

Comment: @AliAkber yes the edges are weighted. In my project, i need to use three methods to find MST : Prim, Kruskal and DFS. I already done Prim and Kruskal even if i'm still struggling with an awkward error. But DFS i still didn't implemented the program.

Comment: Actually i was going to tell you about these kruskal and prims algorithm which can be easily implemented by BFS...
But using DFS to find MST... i never did that :( i will let you know if i come up with a solution

Comment: see this http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/10717/dfs-miniumum-spanning-tree

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like homework, so I'll tell you how I would approach the problem.

First, modify your DFS implementation to use an explicit stack instead of recursion. Create a new array `int stack[10];` and a variable `int stacksize = 0;`. The idea is that `stack[0], stack[1], ..., stack[stacksize-1]` will correspond to the arguments `i` of the outermost active invocation of `DFS` to the innermost. I'll leave the details a bit sketchy because I'm sure that there have been other question/answer pairs about this aspect.

Second, whenever the graph has an edge back to a visited vertex, scan from the top of the stack back to the visited vertex, looking for the heaviest edge. Once you find it, delete that edge by modifying `G`. To restart the depth-first search, pop the stack until you pop one of the endpoints of the deleted edge. Each time you pop something, clear its visited flag. The depth-first search continues from here (a complete restart is not necessary because it would do the same thing up to here).

Comment: thank you, but i don't understand your answer. Andi 'm not able to implement the solution myself, that's why i came here, and tha's why i picked a ready code from internet of dfs. some algorithms are just ready to use, i'm not gonna find a better solution in couple of days. The goal of my project is not learning to code in c, but just knowing difference between practical complexity and the theorical one. I hope you understand my problem :)